# "invalid number" occurs even after where clause - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two records in the table:

```
STORE   VARCHAR2_1
30816   26.399883
30074   29.58.20.9

  SELECT *
    FROM mig_test sce
   WHERE VARCHAR2_1 > 90 
   AND VARCHAR2_1 not LIKE '%.%.%';
```

I am querying: "invalid number". Even when I have excluded the faulty record in the where clause

Comment: I can't reproduce this on livesql.oracle.com. Is it possible the `varchar2_1` column contains some whitespace?

Comment: checked. There are no white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is free to rearrange computations however it likes.  So, that makes your comparison troublesome, because the the value may not be a number.

However, `case` *does* guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM mig_test sce
WHERE (CASE WHEN VARCHAR2_1 NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
            THEN CAST(VARCHAR2_1 as number)
       END) > 90
```

Note that I added in an explicit `cast()`.

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(VARCHAR2_1, '^(9|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

That is, it starts either with 9# or ### and is followed by digits and at most one decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the second condition that raises the error, but the first one:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2      FROM mig_test sce
  3     WHERE VARCHAR2_1 > 90                 --> this
  4     AND VARCHAR2_1 not LIKE '%.%.%';
   WHERE VARCHAR2_1 > 90
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

As the column is `VARCHAR2`, enclose `90` into single quotes:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2      FROM mig_test sce
  3     WHERE VARCHAR2_1 > '90'
  4     AND VARCHAR2_1 not LIKE '%.%.%';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

See whether CAST helps.

```
with valid_values as
  (select store, 
          cast (varchar2_1 as number) varc     --> cast to number
   from mig_test
   where regexp_count(varchar2_1, '\.') <= 1   --> remove invalid rows
  )
select *
From valid_values
where varc > 90;
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ef6aba6eef0a027ffe053bbeed913ccd) is here and looks like this:

[image]Cast as number

Comment: thanks. I want to compare it with numeric 90.  I tried enclosing VARCHAR2_1 TO to_number, but it still shows the same error

Comment: I added some more info; have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it with a sub query and with regexp_count to eliminate the data with more than one full stop `'.'`:

```
select * 
from (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(sce.VARCHAR2_1, '[.]') cnt
             , sce.store  
             , VARCHAR2_1
      FROM mig_test sce)
where cnt = 1
and CAST(VARCHAR2_1 as number) > 90;
```

[Here is a demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=742d4c33c646de75b17964282a2c028b)